# MySQL - three-table tag structure - efficiently getting tag names and counts from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags

I have a pretty standard 3-table tag schema where I have a table named `content` with fields such as `title`, `subtitle`, `text`, etc., a table named `tag` with fields for `id` and `name`, and a table called `content_tag` that joins the two with fields `content_id` and `tag_id`.

I allow the user to search by both tags and keywords. The queries for this look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM content_tag ct, content c, tag t 
WHERE ct.tag_id = t.id 
 AND (t.name IN ('Metal Joints','Joint Set'))
 AND c.id = ct.content_id 
 AND (c.title like '%Te%' or c.subtitle like '%Te%' or c.text like '%Te%' or c.keywords like '%Te%' ) 
GROUP BY c.id HAVING COUNT( c.id )=2 
ORDER BY add_date DESC
```

This query selects all content that have both the tags '`Metal Joints`' and '`Joint Set`' that also contains '`%Te`'. It works well and is not my issue.

My issue is trying to get all the tag names along with their count from this query efficiently. I tried this with subquery `WHERE IN` statements, but they were taking anywhere from 3-5 seconds to complete.

I need help creating a query that will give me a list of tag names and counts contained in the table the above query generates. I can't seem to do it without it taking too long.

EDIT: 
Here's the query I'm using now that takes a few seconds, but works.

```
SELECT tag.name, COUNT(tag.id) as tagCount
FROM content_tag
LEFT JOIN tag
ON content_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE content_tag.content_id IN
(SELECT c.id
FROM content_tag ct, content c, tag t 
WHERE ct.tag_id = t.id 
 AND (t.name IN ('Metal Joints','Joint Set'))
 AND c.id = ct.content_id 
 AND (c.title like '%Te%' or c.subtitle like '%Te%' or c.text like '%Te%' or c.keywords like '%Te%' ) 
GROUP BY c.id HAVING COUNT( c.id )=2 
ORDER BY add_date DESC)
GROUP BY tag.id
```